# Whats wrong with query? wrong syntax error? Group by no working

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have written a query

```
(SELECT TimeStamp, AVG(FwdHr), W 
 FROM Meter_Data 
 WHERE (TimeStamp Between 1370476500 AND 1370477100 AND DeviceID = '1' 
 GROUP BY MeterID ORDER BY TimeStamp) 
UNION 
(SELECT TimeStamp, AVG(FwdHr), W 
 FROM Meter_Data 
 WHERE TimeStamp Between 1370496006 AND 1370496606 AND DeviceID = '1' 
 GROUP BY MeterID ORDER BY TimeStamp)
```

i want to select avg(FwdHr) from table for every meter id between two time stamps

and then union it with same query having different time intervals

Comment: is DeviceId a Varchar or a number? Also post the error you receive.

Comment: @KevinBowersox error - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY MeterID ORDER BY TimeStamp) UNION (SELECT TimeStamp, AVG(FwdHr), W FROM' at line 1

Comment: Why is this tagged `mysql` and `sql-server`?

Comment: I'm having a hard time posting my solution, somethings going haywire, but you have an unclosed left paren, most of the parens are not even required.

Comment: @KevinBowersox - Are you getting an error when trying to extend your answer or something? Maybe put the answer up on pastebin and someone else can have a go at editing it in.

Comment: @MartinSmith Exactly whats happening, have you had this issue before?

Comment: @KevinBowersox - No but I've seen occasional meta posts [such as this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171916/an-error-occurred-submitting-the-answer) so maybe worth checking if there is something in the answer itself that causes problems or just something local to your end.

Comment: @Inderpal Singh- what is the TimeStamp,W in select column?? if it is a column then it should be in group by clause.

Answer (score 0):

The parenthesis in the query are unbalance and unnecessary.

Comment: thats not because of that. i have checked

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY`can only be applied to the final result set, not for intermediate results.
Also the parenthesis are unnecessary

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT TimeStamp, AVG(FwdHr), W 
  FROM Meter_Data 
  WHERE TimeStamp Between 1370476500 AND 1370477100 
  AND DeviceID = '1' 

  UNION 

  SELECT TimeStamp, AVG(FwdHr), W 
  FROM Meter_Data WHERE TimeStamp Between 1370496006 AND 1370496606 
  AND DeviceID = '1' 
) as myTable

GROUP BY myTable.MeterID 
ORDER BY myTable.TimeStamp
```

Or even better: Use `OR` instead of `UNION`

```
SELECT TimeStamp, AVG(FwdHr), W 
FROM Meter_Data 
WHERE DeviceID = '1' 
AND (TimeStamp Between 1370496006 AND 1370496606 
    OR
     TimeStamp Between 1370476500 AND 1370477100 )

GROUP BY MeterID 
ORDER BY TimeStamp
```

Comment: what will this query return?

Comment: Try the second one with OR